# How to set ArrayAdapter properly in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to make a ListView in Android with a dynamic field. First, I tried to set it up using static field which is shown below (String[] chars)

```
String[] chars = {"TEST"};
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.resultlist,chars));
```

it gives me error `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewTranslationsList.GrabURL, int, int) is undefined`. Where's the problem?

I want to add items to the `chars` array before I set up ArrayAdapter in for cycle.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're doing this inside an inner class (since the error is mentioning `ViewTranslationsList.GrabURL`. If that is truly the case, try doing this:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ViewTranslationsList.this,R.layout.resultlist,chars));
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not inside your Activities context when you are calling your ArrayAdapter constructor. Try to change it like this:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(yourActivityName.this,R.layout.resultlist,chars));
```

Though that may not be your only problem because based on the error it seems to think that chars is an int for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

here `this` is `ViewTranslationsList.GrabURL`

```
ListView l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.some)
l.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SomeActivity.this,R.layout.resultlist,chars));
```

you have to pass `Context`, `ViewTranslationsList.GrabURL` is not `Context`

Answer (score 0):

im not about your problem, but if you dont now about standard layout in android.

```
  l.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SomeActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,chars));
```

or

```
l.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(SomeActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_activated,chars));
```

or

```
l.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (SomeActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,chars));
l.setOnChoise(LISTVIEW.SET_MULTICHOISE_MODE);
```

read about standard layout. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html